# Bookworm GPIO pins 8 and 17 busy

Tags: gpio, raspberry-pi-os-bookworm

I would like to use a Waveshare e-paper display but running their test software gives this error. When I check with `gpioinfo` pins 17 and 8 are already being used by something and this giving this error. Can I just switch the pin allocation to an unused GPIO pin, say 27 and 9?

The pins giving this error are: CS (CE0/24) and RST (17/11)

```
pi@jayofelony:~ $ uname -a
Linux jayofelony 6.1.0-rpi8-rpi-v8 #1 SMP PREEMPT Debian 1:6.1.73-1+rpt1 (2024-01-25) aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

[image: gpioinfo]
[image: waveshare pinout and python script]

```
pi@jayofelony:~/e-Paper/RaspberryPi_JetsonNano/python/examples $ python3 epd_2in13_V2_test.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gpiozero/pins/pi.py", line 408, in pin
    pin = self.pins[info]
          ~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^
KeyError: PinInfo(number=11, name='GPIO17', names=frozenset({'GPIO17', 'J8:11', 17, 'BCM17', 'BOARD11', '17', 'WPI0'}), pull='', row=6, col=1, interfaces=frozenset({'', 'spi', 'gpio', 'dpi', 'uart'}))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/e-Paper/RaspberryPi_JetsonNano/python/examples/epd_2in13_V2_test.py", line 11, in <module>
    from waveshare_epd import epd2in13_V2
  File "/home/pi/e-Paper/RaspberryPi_JetsonNano/python/lib/waveshare_epd/epd2in13_V2.py", line 32, in <module>
    from . import epdconfig
  File "/home/pi/e-Paper/RaspberryPi_JetsonNano/python/lib/waveshare_epd/epdconfig.py", line 276, in <module>
    implementation = RaspberryPi()
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/pi/e-Paper/RaspberryPi_JetsonNano/python/lib/waveshare_epd/epdconfig.py", line 52, in __init__
    self.GPIO_RST_PIN    = gpiozero.LED(self.RST_PIN)
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gpiozero/devices.py", line 103, in __call__
    self = super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gpiozero/output_devices.py", line 192, in __init__
    super().__init__(pin, active_high=active_high,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gpiozero/output_devices.py", line 74, in __init__
    super().__init__(pin, pin_factory=pin_factory)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gpiozero/mixins.py", line 75, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gpiozero/devices.py", line 549, in __init__
    pin = self.pin_factory.pin(pin)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gpiozero/pins/pi.py", line 410, in pin
    pin = self.pin_class(self, info)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gpiozero/pins/lgpio.py", line 126, in __init__
    lgpio.gpio_claim_input(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lgpio.py", line 755, in gpio_claim_input
    return _u2i(_lgpio._gpio_claim_input(handle&0xffff, lFlags, gpio))
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lgpio.py", line 458, in _u2i
    raise error(error_text(v))
lgpio.error: 'GPIO busy'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I just switch the pin allocation to an unused GPIO pin, say 27 and 9?

No, you can't do that. What needs to be done is to change a **parameter** in `/boot/firmware/config.txt`:

I had `dtoverlay=spi1-3cs` in my `/boot/firmware/config.txt`. I switched this to `dtoverlay=spi0-0cs` and now it works.

Comment: Congratulations for figuring this out on your own!  Please don't forget to "Accept" your answer when you can - that lets others know this answer contains a solution.

Comment: Yes, I have to wait another hour to do so.